# Сортировка list c использованием STL алгоритма sort

Tags: c++, сортировка, list, stl, qsort

Хочу отсортировать список с использованием функции sort из STL, но при попытке компиляции выдает ошибку. Подскажите, что делаю не так, и какой есть тогда аналог!
`   list a = { 3,2,1,5 };
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());

```
for (auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); it++) {
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аналог - [`sort` в `list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort):

```
list a = { 3,2,1,5 }; 
a.sort(  );
```

См. https://ideone.com/2L5VhP

Comment: А ларчик просто открывался... Спасибо за ответ! Странно, что для vector можно просто использовать метод sort из STL, а для list - метод экземпляра класса

Comment: Потому что у `list` нет способа быстро перейти к нужному элементу - как это можно у вектора. Там итератор произвольного доступа, а у списка - только последовательный... Если ответ устроил - закрывайте вопрос ("птичка" слева от ответа).